# How to change the values in drawable files?

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, android-resources, android-vectordrawable

I am developing an android App. I am using a drawable xml file to draw an arc.

**My Problem**
I want to change a particular attribute's value in the drawable xml file programmatically.

I want to change `android:dashWidth` attributes value using java code.

**Steps Taken** 
I searched stackoverflow , But there are only answers for changing color in the drawable xml .(So may not be a duplicate question)

Here my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:height="56dp"
                android:width="56dp"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="6dp"
                android:color="#cccccc"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:height="50dp"
                android:width="50dp"/>
            <stroke

                android:width="6dp"
                android:dashGap="140dp"
                android:dashWidth="79dp" <!-- want to CHANGE this -->
                android:color="#ecc807"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

> Here I want to change the `android:dashWidth` attribute's value using java code.
>   How to achieve this ?

Comment: 1. get drawable 2. cast to LayerDrawable 3. get second drawable 4. cast it to `ShapeDrawable` 5. use `ValueAnimator` ( in `onAnimationUpdate` use `circle.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(animator.getAnimatedValue())` where `circle` is `ShapeDrawable` from point 4)

Comment: @Selvin .. Will you please give me a sample code. I am new to Android and very new to Android Drawables